# Expected type 'Mapped[bool | None]', got 'bool' instead - IDE Warning transition to SQLAlchemy 2.0 Declarative style

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pycharm, warnings

I'm working on transitioning the database portion of project from SQLAlchemy 1.4 to 2.0. I'm trying to use the Mapped class and mapped_column format recommended in the new version (rather than the Column() format...though I realize this should continue to work for the foreseeable future). However, when I do this, I receive IDE warnings in the class methods that edit these values.

Here is some simplified code that shows the warning:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column
from typing import Optional


class SQLAlchemyBase(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class TestModel(SQLAlchemyBase):
    __tablename__ = "my_table"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    my_string: Mapped[str]
    yes_no: Mapped[Optional[bool]]

    def my_method(self):
        self.yes_no = True
        self.my_string = "abc"
```

The error I receive in my IDE (PyCharm 2023.1.1) is for the last two lines, and they are:

`self.yes_no = True`
`Expected type 'Mapped[bool | None]', got 'bool' instead`

`self.my_string = "abc"`
`Expected type 'Mapped[str]', got 'str' instead`

I understand why the warning is happening, since a Mapped[bool] is obvious not a bool, but this can't be expected behavior. Plus, everything works properly, so maybe I'm just OCD. I also know that there a couple of ways to suppress the warnings. However, the fact that I'm getting the warning makes me think that I'm doing something wrong that will eventually come back to bite me.

Is my mapping incorrect? Should I be using `self.yes_no = Mapped[True]`, which works, but seems silly and excessive. Is it just bad form to put methods in these classes based on DeclarativeBase?

I've scoured the SQLAlchemy documentation, but none of their examples include methods, so I've been unable to find an answer.

Comment: I get warnings in PyCharm, but not in VSCode, so this is more of a "PyCharm thing" than a "SQLAlchemy thing".

Comment: FYI, its being discussed in Jetbrains issue tracker here, without any noticeable progress so far: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-59791/Wrong-type-of-SQLAlchemy-2.0-attributes-declared-using-Mapped